# In below code , layout weight not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I want to set `layout_weight` with `viewpager` 40% and recyclerview 60% in below code. But its not showing properly.It not showing properly in 6.0 but works perfectly in above 6.0 versions.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">     
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:padding="10dip"
                app:centered="true"
                app:radius="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:pageColor="#e5e5e5"
                app:fillColor="#ffffff"
                app:snap="false" />

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/rcv"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView> 
           </LinearLayout>
```

Below is my activity where i am replacing this fragment file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.laundry.laundryapp.activity.Navigation_drawer">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.example.laundry.laundryapp.activity.Navigation_drawer">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/navigation">
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: in your code you set it to 1 and 2, and expect it to be 40/60? Why? I can't find any math or logical way how can 1/2 be converted to 40/60. if you have o idea how weihgt works, then you probably need to watch some tutorial about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Hey, I read somewhere that it is recommended to assign weight to all
>   the children of the parent layout. Also, it is important to include
>   weightSum in the parent view and the height of the views should be 0dp (or width in case the orientation is "horizontal")

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:weightSum="20">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:centered="true"

        app:radius="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:pageColor="#e5e5e5"
        app:fillColor="#ffffff"
        app:snap="false" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/rcv"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this code, also try adjusting the weights to get the desired look. Hope this works.

Comment: no its not working in fragment. It works properly in separeate activity. But when i use it in fragment and replacing fragment on drawer item click, its not showing properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set android:layout_weight="0.4" and android:layout_weight="0.6"

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstrainLayout combined with Guidelines (in percentage for sure), it's way more easier to arrive what you are looking for.